# Show/hide list items based on search value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following list which is brought through AJAX, each 'li' haves a default 'display: none' value (the list haves 800 'li' so here I cut it to show only 3):

Basically I need that when somebody types a value in a search field to go through that whole list comparing that value with the 'h3 > a' text inside each list, so lets say somebody type "Florida" if it's inside an 'h3 > a' show it, the rest keep it hidden.

Also when somebody change the search value for example to "California" it should go again through all the list, hiding the actual ones (in this case "Florida") and showing the ones that haves "California" text in their h3 > a.

Thank you!

```
<form method="post" action="/employers/">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Employer search</legend>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="searchtext" class="hidden">Search employers</label>
            <div class="clear-input js-clear-input">
                <input id="searchtext" type="text" name="RecruiterName" value="Florida" placeholder="Start typing…" class="clear-input__input js-recruiter-lookup js-clear-input-input" autocomplete="off">
                    <i data-icon="x" class="clear-input__trigger icon-before js-clear-input-trigger" style="display: inline;"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <select name="RecruiterTypeId" class="js-recruiter-type">
                    <option value="">All</option>
                    <option value="-10">Employer</option>
                    <option value="-20">Search Firm</option>
                    <option value="513012">Advertising Agency</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="RecruiterId" value="" class="js-recruiter-id">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" id="search" class="button button--brand">
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

**Actual code which is not working (it shows me the whole list):**

```js
// Detect a click in the "Search" button or enter from keyboard
$('#search').on('click keyup', function(event) {
  // Prevent the original click for not reloading the whole page
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get value from search input #search
  var searchInputValue = $('#search').val();
  
  

  // Search the list and if it matches display it, else hide it
  $('.lister__item').each(function() {
    var isMatch = $('.lister__item > h3 > a:contains(' + searchInputValue + ')');
    $(this).parent().parent().toggle(isMatch);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="search" id="search" />
</div>
<div class="employers-list">
  <ul>
    <li class="lister__item cf block js-clickable">
      <h3 class="lister__header">
        <a href="/employer/1208/american-international-college/" class="js-clickable-area-link pipe">American International College</a><small>
        <a href="/employer/1208/american-international-college/#listing-header">19 jobs</a></small>
      </h3>
      <img src="//careers.insidehighered.com/getasset/823f0d7b-4f21-4303-b8a3-dac30651e57c/" alt="" class="lister__logo rec-logo float-right one-quarter portable-two-fifths palm-two-fifths">
      <p class="no-margin">American International College is a private, coeducational institution of higher education located on a 70+ acre campus in Springfield, Massachusetts</p>
    </li>
    <li class="lister__item cf block js-clickable">
      <h3 class="lister__header">
        <a href="/employer/1297911/american-national-university/" class="js-clickable-area-link pipe">American National University</a><small>
        <a href="/employer/1297911/american-national-university/#listing-header">1 job</a></small>
      </h3>
      <p class="no-margin">&nbsp;In 1886, a group of visionary educators and business leaders saw the need for an higher education institution focused on career-based training to meet workforce needs in the southeastern United States. Together they founded what is now known as Am...</p>
    </li>
    <li class="lister__item cf block js-clickable">
      <h3 class="lister__header">
        <a href="/employer/1226/american-university-in-dubai/" class="js-clickable-area-link pipe">American University in Dubai</a><small>
        <a href="/employer/1226/american-university-in-dubai/#listing-header">12 jobs</a></small>
      </h3>
      <img src="//careers.insidehighered.com/getasset/f729bc47-b147-4656-9ff0-7faf9e660a4c/" alt="" class="lister__logo rec-logo float-right one-quarter portable-two-fifths palm-two-fifths">
      <p class="no-margin">The American University in Dubai is a private, non-sectarian institution of higher learning founded in 1995</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Actual working code:**

```
// Disable form since we need first the list loaded for being used
$('form').css('display', 'none');

// Get the total amount of pages
var totalPagesCount = $('.paginator__item:last-child a').attr('href').split('/')[2];

// Create a div container for adding future employers list and not being deleted later when the onclick occurs
$('<div />').addClass('employers-list').appendTo('#listing');

// Get every employer from the all the pages
for(var i=0; i<totalPagesCount; i++) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://careers.insidehighered.com/employers/' + (i+1),
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(results) {
      // Get all the elements and hide them
      var page = $(results).find('.lister__item').hide().detach();
      // Add them to the empty 'ul'
      $('.employers-list').append(page);
    },
    complete: function() {
      // Everything is loaded so show form again
      $('form').css('display', 'inline-block');
    }
  });
}

$.expr[":"].contains_ci = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
  return function( elem ) {
    return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  };
});

// Detect a click in the "Search" button or enter from keyboard
$('#search').on('click keyup', function(event) {
  // Prevent the original click for not reloading the whole page
  event.preventDefault();

  // Empty initial list
  $('#listing').children('li').remove();

  // Remove the paginator
  $('.paginator').remove();

  // Get value from search input
  var searchInputValue = $('#searchtext').val();

  $('.lister__item').hide().find('h3 > a:contains_ci(' + searchInputValue + ')').parents('.lister__item').show();
});
```

Comment: can you add your search and search text on the markup

Comment: @Geeky there I added the search button :)

Basically this is the website: https://careers.insidehighered.com/employers/

The code it bigger (I can give it all to you to try it inside the Google dev console if you want), I'm bringing all the pages list through AJAX and adding them in a hidden div, when somebody makes a search it should detect the 'h3 > a' that contains and show it, if not hide it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hide all elements first then show the matched elements
Also I've added contains_ci expression which allows search case-insensitive

```js
 $.expr[":"].contains_ci = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
   return function( elem ) {
     return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
   };
 });

// Detect a click in the "Search" button or enter from keyboard
$('#search').on('click keyup', function(event) {
  // Prevent the original click for not reloading the whole page
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get value from search input
  var searchInputValue = $('#search').val();

  // Search the list and if it matches display it, else hide it
  $('.lister__item').hide().find('h3 > a:contains_ci(' + searchInputValue + ')').parents('.lister__item').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="search" id="search" />
</div>
<div class="employers-list">
  <ul>
    <li class="lister__item cf block js-clickable">
      <h3 class="lister__header">
        <a href="/employer/1208/american-international-college/" class="js-clickable-area-link pipe">American International College</a><small>
        <a href="/employer/1208/american-international-college/#listing-header">19 jobs</a></small>
      </h3>
      <img src="//careers.insidehighered.com/getasset/823f0d7b-4f21-4303-b8a3-dac30651e57c/" alt="" class="lister__logo rec-logo float-right one-quarter portable-two-fifths palm-two-fifths">
      <p class="no-margin">American International College is a private, coeducational institution of higher education located on a 70+ acre campus in Springfield, Massachusetts</p>
    </li>
    <li class="lister__item cf block js-clickable">
      <h3 class="lister__header">
        <a href="/employer/1297911/american-national-university/" class="js-clickable-area-link pipe">American National University</a><small>
        <a href="/employer/1297911/american-national-university/#listing-header">1 job</a></small>
      </h3>
      <p class="no-margin">&nbsp;In 1886, a group of visionary educators and business leaders saw the need for an higher education institution focused on career-based training to meet workforce needs in the southeastern United States. Together they founded what is now known as Am...</p>
    </li>
    <li class="lister__item cf block js-clickable">
      <h3 class="lister__header">
        <a href="/employer/1226/american-university-in-dubai/" class="js-clickable-area-link pipe">American University in Dubai</a><small>
        <a href="/employer/1226/american-university-in-dubai/#listing-header">12 jobs</a></small>
      </h3>
      <img src="//careers.insidehighered.com/getasset/f729bc47-b147-4656-9ff0-7faf9e660a4c/" alt="" class="lister__logo rec-logo float-right one-quarter portable-two-fifths palm-two-fifths">
      <p class="no-margin">The American University in Dubai is a private, non-sectarian institution of higher learning founded in 1995</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you a lot, it works perfectly! :D

One last question, I added my actual code at the question, I would like to block the search button until the AJAX brought and added in the DOM all the list, I'm able to hide it and show it in the success function but it's showing it before they're added in the DOM and ready to go, can you point me out please on how to make the form ready only once the AJAX finished bringing the list and adding them in the DOM please?

Thank you again!

Comment: You are using for loop for batch ajax requests. So, when one of your requests completed it will trigger complete callback and you will have that issue. You may use promises to wait all of your requests completed then you can show your form. Then it will work. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Thanks again for everything @Tolgahan!

Answer (score 0):

I took what you had and used a [JavaScript RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to construct a case-insensitive expression to match in your content. I'm also using `$(this)` to target the element in the loop.

```js
// Detect a click in the "Search" button or enter from keyboard
$('#search').on('click keyup', function(event) {
  // Prevent the original click for not reloading the whole page
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get value from search input
  var searchInputString = $('#searchtext').val();
  var regExp = new RegExp(searchInputString, 'i');

  // Search the list and if it matches display it, else hide it
  $('.lister__item').each(function() {
    var isMatch = $(this).find('h3 > a').text().match(regExp);
    $(this).toggle((isMatch) ? true : false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchtext" type="text">
<button id="search">Search</button>
<div class="employers-list">
  <ul>
    <li class="lister__item cf block js-clickable">
      <h3 class="lister__header">
        <a href="/employer/1208/american-international-college/" class="js-clickable-area-link pipe">American International College</a><small>
        <a href="/employer/1208/american-international-college/#listing-header">19 jobs</a></small>
      </h3>
      <img src="//careers.insidehighered.com/getasset/823f0d7b-4f21-4303-b8a3-dac30651e57c/" alt="" class="lister__logo rec-logo float-right one-quarter portable-two-fifths palm-two-fifths">
      <p class="no-margin">American International College is a private, coeducational institution of higher education located on a 70+ acre campus in Springfield, Massachusetts</p>
    </li>
    <li class="lister__item cf block js-clickable">
      <h3 class="lister__header">
        <a href="/employer/1297911/american-national-university/" class="js-clickable-area-link pipe">American National University</a><small>
        <a href="/employer/1297911/american-national-university/#listing-header">1 job</a></small>
      </h3>
      <p class="no-margin">&nbsp;In 1886, a group of visionary educators and business leaders saw the need for an higher education institution focused on career-based training to meet workforce needs in the southeastern United States. Together they founded what is now known as Am...</p>
    </li>
    <li class="lister__item cf block js-clickable">
      <h3 class="lister__header">
        <a href="/employer/1226/american-university-in-dubai/" class="js-clickable-area-link pipe">American University in Dubai</a><small>
        <a href="/employer/1226/american-university-in-dubai/#listing-header">12 jobs</a></small>
      </h3>
      <img src="//careers.insidehighered.com/getasset/f729bc47-b147-4656-9ff0-7faf9e660a4c/" alt="" class="lister__logo rec-logo float-right one-quarter portable-two-fifths palm-two-fifths">
      <p class="no-margin">The American University in Dubai is a private, non-sectarian institution of higher learning founded in 1995</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Daerik!

One last question, I added my actual code at the question, I would like to block the search button until the AJAX brought and added in the DOM all the list, I'm able to hide it and show it in the success function but it's showing it before they're added in the DOM and ready to go, can you point me out please on how to make the form ready only once the AJAX finished bringing the list and adding them in the DOM please?

Thank you again!

Comment: AJAX has a callback. Just read the documentation and block the search button with the `[disabled]` attribute.